# SUMPRODUCT with VLOOKUP

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm trying to get the Product and Sum of what matches in the TC Ref column and the Earn Type.

For example 7926 would be (45.32 x -3) + (45.32 x -3) + (45.32 x -4) for REG and (45.32 x -4) for OT.

I tried a SUMPRODUCT with a VLOOKUP but only getting the first line that matches. I have another table that I'm trying to return the value to.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(VLOOKUP([@[TC Ref]],Table_timecard,2,FALSE),VLOOKUP([@[TC Ref]],Table_timecard,3,FALSE))
```

Current Formula: (Is there a better way to do this?)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Timecard!$A$2:$A$5574=[@[TC Ref]])*(Timecard!$J$2:$J$5574="REG"),Timecard!$H$2:$H$5574,Timecard!$I$2:$I$5574)
```

Combine Formula: (Is there a way to combine the J2:J5574 to find all the types REG, ADDTL, FMHOL, SHIFT)

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(Timecard!$A$2:$A$5574=[@[TC Ref]])*(Timecard!$J$2:$J$5574="REG"),Timecard!$H$2:$H$5574,Timecard!$I$2:$I$5574)+SUMPRODUCT(--(Timecard!$A$2:$A$5574=[@[TC Ref]])*(Timecard!$J$2:$J$5574="ADDTL"),Timecard!$H$2:$H$5574,Timecard!$I$2:$I$5574)+SUMPRODUCT(--(Timecard!$A$2:$A$5574=[@[TC Ref]])*(Timecard!$J$2:$J$5574="FMHOL"),Timecard!$H$2:$H$5574,Timecard!$I$2:$I$5574)+SUMPRODUCT(--(Timecard!$A$2:$A$5574=[@[TC Ref]])*(Timecard!$J$2:$J$5574="SHIFT"),Timecard!$H$2:$H$5574,Timecard!$I$2:$I$5574)
```

Example data:

```
TC Ref Pay Rate     Hours   Earn Type

7926     $45.32     -3      REG
7926     $45.32     -3      REG
7926     $45.32     -4      OT
7927     $45.32      3      REG
7927     $45.32      7      REG
7927     $45.32      3      DT
7927     $45.32      3      OT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `SUMPRODUCT` formula like this

`=SUMPRODUCT((Timecard!$A$2:$A$5574=[@[TC Ref]])*ISNUMBER(MATCH(Timecard!$J$2:$J$5574,{"REG","ADDTL","FMHOL","SHIFT"},0)),Timecard!$H$2:$H$5574,Timecard!$I$2:$I$5574)`

`MATCH` function matches `J2:J5574` against an "array constant" containing your 4 values - if there's a match then `MATCH` returns a number, otherwise you get #N/A error - `ISNUMBER` function then converts that to `TRUE` or `FALSE` which we can use in `SUMPRODUCT` when multiplied with your first condition

Answer (score 0):

I could get it to work using a helper column as shown below

```
TC Ref  Pay Rate    Hours   Value   Earn Type
7926    45.32          -3   -135.96 REG
7926    45.32          -3   -135.96 REG
7926    45.32          -4   -181.28 OT
7927    45.32           3   135.96  REG
7927    45.32           7   317.24  REG
7927    45.32           3   135.96  DT
7927    45.32           3   135.96  OT
```

In the end if you list the unique values in the TC Ref col such as

```
7926  -453.2  
7927   725.12
```

[image]

The above figure shows the formulas used against each of the TC Ref.

Comment: I'm sure there should be a straight forward way to achieve this